# How to alter column to make it primary key when one already exists mysql8?

Tags: mysql, primary-key, mysql-8.0, alter-table, alter-database

```
 id         | bigint unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
 | title      | varchar(255)    | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
 | category   | varchar(255)    | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
 | summary    | varchar(10000)  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
 | detail     | mediumtext      | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
 | created_at | timestamp       | YES  |     | NULL    |                |   
 | updated_at | timestamp       | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
 | image      | mediumblob      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
 | image1     | mediumblob      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
 | image3     | mediumblob      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
 | phold      | varchar(50)     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
 +------------+-----------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

I have this database now,I want to make a one-one relationship with with another table with where I use column `( title )` to link specific data. When I run

```
mysql> alter table tours add primary key (id,title);
```

OR

```
mysql> alter table tours add constraint pk_tours primary key (id, title);
```

The error:

```
ERROR 1068 (42000): Multiple primary key defined
```

on both queries.

I want another table named itinery where I use to link it with former table with help of volumn title ;

I am using mysql 8 with laravel 8.
Thanks

Comment: `ALTER TABLE DROP PRIMARY KEY, ADD PRIMARY KEY (...)` -- but that is probably not what you really wanted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you would like to have other tables reference *just* the `title` field, then you can add a `UNIQUE` index.

First, edit the `tours` table to add a `NOT NULL` constraint to the `title` field:

```
ALTER TABLE `tours` MODIFY `title` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL;
```

Now you can create the index:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX `udx_title` ON `tours` (`title`);
```

Be sure to confirm that all values in `title` are unique *before* doing this. Once done, you will be able to have other tables reference the field.

> *Hat tip to Vérace for pointing out that* `title` *could be* `NULL`, *which we do not want.*

Comment: Thanks, Do you help in making another table, I want column of another table be linked with 1-1 relationship with the phold column of this table. How can I do that?

Comment: so far I tried, 
```
      CREATE TABLE itinery(
     id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
     day VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
     title varchar(255) not null,
     PRIMARY KEY(title),
     FOREIGN KEY(title) REFERENCES tours(title)
     ) ENGINE = InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET = utf8;
```

I want column-> title in this table be linked with phold column of tours , so that i can relate retrieve data using their title.